# Proving or Disproving the Existence of a Function on the Unit Disc

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be holomorphic in the unit disc and continuous on its closure. Prove or disprove that there exists such $f$ so that $f(e^{i\theta})=e^{-i\theta}$ for $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{4}$.

I believe that there is no such function since on the boundary of the disc it acts as the map $z\mapsto \bar{z}$, which is not holomorphic. But I don't see how to prove this rigorously, nor do I see what known theorems could be applied. I am familiar with analytic continuation, but I am not sure if that applies since $f$ need not be holomorphic on the boundary. Any hints or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function $g(z)=f(z)$ if $|z|\leq1$, $g(z)=1/z$ if $z=r e^{i\theta}$, $0<\theta<\pi/4$, $r\geq 1$ (say). It is continuous and holomorphic except perhaps on the arc $e^{i\theta}$, $0<\theta<\pi/4$. By Morera theorem it is then holomorphic everywhere (where defined), and so it must coincide with $1/z$, which is however not holomorphic at $z=0$. So such $f$ doesn't exist.

Comment: should your first inequality be strict? otherwise, I don't see the point of introducing a function $g$.

Comment: can you clarify your use of Morera? Isn't that a theorem which involves line integrals - I don't see the connection.

Comment: I believe he's using the fact that $1/z=\bar{z}$ when $|z|=1$ as shown by the relation $1=|z|^2=z\bar{z}$. Since the set of zeros of the function $f(z)-1/z$ has an accumulation point, it must be identically zero, and hence $f$ and $1/z$ are identical where defined. So $1/z$ can be seen as an analytic continuation of $f$. However $1/z$ is not holomorphic in the unit disk so no such $f$ can exist. (Since $f$ is assumed to be holomorphic at $z=0$.)

Comment: @TheSubstitute Morera thm is used to prove that g, which is a priori just continuous, is in fact holomorphic. As for those inequalities, g seems to me well-defined (but feel free to replace one of them with strict inequality). g is just a tool to see that f is 1/z, which gives a contradiction

Answer (score 2):

Such holomorphic function could not exist. Before delving into the proof, I think it is important to see the underlying key idea (lemma, if you will)

> **Lemma:** If $f$ is a holomorphic function on the unit disk and continuous on its boundary ($S^1$); furthermore $f$ is identically zero on some arc (say, the first quarter of the upper-half arc) of $S^1$, then $f$ is also identically zero on the closure of the unit disk.

Knowing this, the problem is more or less easy now. Indeed, define $g(z):=zf(z)-1$. Then certainly, $g$ enjoys all the properties of $f$, i.e., $g$ is a holomorphic function on the unit disk and continuous on $S^1$. Furthermore for every $z=e^{i\theta},$ whenever $0<\theta<\pi/4$, $g(e^{i\theta})=e^{i\theta}e^{-i\theta}-1=0.$ In other words, $g$ is *identically zero* on the first quarter of the upper-half arc of $S^1$. So the above lemma tells us that $g\equiv 0$. Therefore, $zf(z)=1,$ for all $z\in \bar D(0,1)$. Now there are many things that will go wrong here if this is true. For example here is one way to see this:

Note that $f$ can't have any zero on $D(0,1)$; or else, say, $z_0$ is a zero, then $0=z_0f(z_0)=1$ (!). Thus $z\mapsto 1/f(z)$ is a well-defined holomorphic map on the unit disk that is also continuous on the boundary. The Maximum modulus principle tells us that $z \mapsto 1/f(z)$ achieves its maximum somewhere on the boundary. But since $zf(z)=1$, $|1/f(z)|=1$ on the boundary. Therefore, $|1/f(z)|\leq 1$ on $D(0,1)$. Or $|f(z)|\geq 1$ on $D(0,1)$. There is nothing to prevent us from repeating the same argument to find that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ on $D(0,1)$. So $|f(z)|\equiv 1$ on $D(0,1)$.

Let $z_0=re^{i\theta}$ be a point inside the disk. Then $r=|z_0|=|z_0f(z_0)|=1$. But this is clearly non-sense because $r<1$. So we are done.

Now back to the proof of the lemma, to see this is true, consider $$h(z)=f(z)f(e^{i\pi/4}z)f(e^{i2\pi/4})f(e^{i3\pi/4})f(e^{i4\pi/4})f(-z)f(-e^{i\pi/4}z)f(-e^{i2\pi/4})f(-e^{i3\pi/4})f(-e^{i4\pi/4}).$$ Note that $h$ now is a holomorphic function on the unit disk, continuous on the boundary, and also *identically zero* on the boundary. So $h\equiv 0$ on the the whole disk. Then the uniqueness of analytic continuation (or principle of isolated zero, either one is fine) tells us that $f$ must also be identically zero on the disk (and its closure too!).

Hope this helps!

Comment: A more general version of the lemma you stated above is the identity theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

Comment: Ah, very nice! I always thought that $f$ and $g$ have to agree on a set that has limit points so that they agree on everywhere. But this theorem states something that is much stronger. Neat. Thank you.

Comment: No, you only need an accumulation point, but you can always add it to your set, as as the functions will agree there by continuity. Thus your statement is equivalent to the one in the wiki page.

Comment: That's true. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: Doesn't the identity theorem (as stated on WIkipedia) assume that the accumulation point lies in the domain $D$, rather than in the closure $\overline{D}$?

Comment: @MattRosenzweig Yes, it does. I don't know it the theorem is false if the accumulation point does not lie in $D$, but maybe you can do something taking functions with an essential singularity or something to get a counterexample.

Comment: Related for the lemma: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407070